# How to combine several rows from one table with one row from another with each row a separate column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to combine multiple rows from one table with another table to one row in the result. My tables are designed as such:

or similar.

Any ideas? There is a finite amount(<10) of available Tags given.

Any standard joins i've tried would give me several rows for a result with the same customer_id

Table 1:

```
CUSTOMER_ID |  FIRSTNAME |  LASTNAME
1 |  ALICE |  MILLER
2 |  BOB |  SMITH
```

Table 2:

```
ID  |   CUSTOMER_ID |   TAG
1 |  1 |  PRO-CUSTOMER
2 |  1 |  ADMIN
3 |  2 |  PRO CUSTOMER
...
```

And i need a result/view like

```
ID |  FIRSTNAME |  LASTNAME |  TAG |  TAG
1 |  ALICE |  MILLER |  PRO CUSTOMER |  ADMIN
2 |  BOB |  SMITH |  PRO CUSTOMER |
```

or similar...

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query has a fixed set of columns.  You can do what you want with two tag columns as:

```
select t1.customerid, t1.firstname, t1.lastname,
       min(t2.tag) as tag1,
       (case when min(t2.tag) <> max(t2.tag) then max(t2.tag)
        end) as tag2
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.customerid = t2.customerid
group by t1.customerid, t1.firstname, t1.lastname;
```

If you simply want a list of tags -- regardless of the length (well, up to 4000 characters) -- you can use `listagg()`:

```
select t1.customerid, t1.firstname, t1.lastname,
       listagg(t2.tag, ',') within group (order by t2.id) as tags
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.customerid = t2.customerid
group by t1.customerid, t1.firstname, t1.lastname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function to give each tag in `table2` an incrementing unique number for each customer and then `PIVOT` the output from rows to columns and then join this to `table1`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 ( CUSTOMER_ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'ALICE', 'MILLER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'BOB',   'SMITH' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( ID, CUSTOMER_ID, TAG ) AS 
  SELECT 1, 1, 'PRO-CUSTOMER' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 1, 'ADMIN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 2, 'PRO CUSTOMER' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT t1.customer_id,
       t1.firstname,
       t1.lastname,
       t2.tag1,
       t2.tag2,
       t2.tag3,
       t2.tag4  -- increase until you reach your maximum number of tags.
FROM   table1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (
         SELECT *
         FROM   ( SELECT customer_id, tag,
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY tag, id ) AS rn
                  FROM   table2 )
         PIVOT ( MAX( tag ) FOR rn IN (
           1 AS tag1,
           2 AS tag2,
           3 AS tag3,
           4 AS tag4 -- increase until you reach your maximum number of tags.
         )
       ) t2
       ON ( t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id );
```

**Output**:

```
CUSTOMER_ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | TAG1         | TAG2         | TAG3 | TAG4
----------: | :-------- | :------- | :----------- | :----------- | :--- | :---
          1 | ALICE     | MILLER   | ADMIN        | PRO-CUSTOMER | null | null
          2 | BOB       | SMITH    | PRO CUSTOMER | null         | null | null
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fe2971af65a844b3adbb99dbf75afcb8)*